# C# and variable number of parameters

Tags: c#, parameters

I tried the following code:

```
class Program: ProgParent
    {

        public int Max(params int[] op)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        public int Max(int i, params int[] op)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        public int Max(int i, int j, params int[] op)
        {
            return 2;
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine((new Program()).Max(5, 6, 7, 8));
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

It executes, and uses the most specific function available. But the compiler gives no warning or error about this. Why?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile - the first two method signatures are identical. After removing one of them it's fine though. Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: Yes, that was the original version, I just wanted to add a new method here

Comment: your code does just fine, after I remove the base class (class Program instead of class Program: ProgParent). I don't know where your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C# language spec says:

> When performing overload resolution, a method with a parameter array
>   may be applicable either in its normal form [i.e. passing an array] or
>   its expanded form [i.e. passing a variable number of parameters]. The
>   expanded form of a method is available only if the normal form of the
>   method is not available and only if a method with the same signature
>   as the expanded form is not already declared in the same type"

In a (slightly simplified) nutshell: If overload resolution is ambiguous, the compiler chooses the non-params overload.

I guess the reasons for that decision (instead of making code like yours illegal) include:

- If your method has the signature: void fn(params object[] p), you want to have some way to call the "normal form" (by passing an object[]). So the compiler has to handle ambiguous cases anyway.
- Creating a temporary array is a lot more expensive than a method call, so you might want to create non-params overloads with 1,2,3 parameters that behave the same but are more efficient. (like e.g. String.Format)

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the build errors (which I'm putting down to typos) - what warning would you expect or want? It is finding a matching overload and using it...

Strictly speaking, I can call different overloads - by passing arrays, but yes, the usage isn't entirely clear.

Without the multiple overloads with `params`, this pattern is used quite heavily in things like `string.Concat` etc (which underpins `+` for strings under the bonnet).